# How to write a template or set of template functions for checking all given containers have the same size (length) in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I would like to write a variadic template function that takes an arbitrary number of containers of any type (though realistically I will only use it for vectors I would say), and return `true` if they all have the same `size` (so `.size()` method or `std::size` (same thing)).  I tried to implement this using my own understanding of template programming but I failed.  I tried to use a set of recursive functions to this end but without luck, it's clear to me that the wrong functions are being chosen by the compiler.

## My implementation attempt, with reasoning

This is the function that I would like to be called first, and is the entry point.  I have two arguments, one normal template argument and another as a parameter pack.  This is so I can separate the "head" from the "tail" (which I am used to with car and cdr from lisp, maybe this is the wrong paradigm here though).

```
template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
bool all_equal_in_size(Arg arg, Args... args) {
    auto size = arg.size();
    return (size == all_equal_in_size(size, args...));
}
```

This should be the function called recursively, same as above but with the state (size) provided additionally in the parameter list.  This is also familiar to me from functional programming, as a means to propagate state through a recursive call chain.

```
template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
bool all_equal_in_size(std::size_t n, Arg arg, Args... args) {
    return ((n == arg.size()) && all_equal_in_size(args...));
}
```

This is simply the terminal condition, and ends the recursive call chain.

```
template <typename T> bool all_equal_in_size(unsigned long n, T ele) {
    return (n == ele.size());
}
```

### The Problem

So in essence I would like to use it like this (sorry if ctor args are wrong, point is I want some containers with length 5):

```
std::vector<int> v1(5);
std::vector<int> v2(5);
std::vector<float> v3(5);
std::vector<double> v4(5);
std::list<int> v5(5);

all_of_equal_size(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5); // == true
```

But when I try to do this I find that the compiler complains because the wrong functions are found:

```
bunch.hpp:13:24: error: member reference base type 'unsigned long' is not a structure or union
    auto size = arg.size();
```

It's trying to call `size` on a long, which I don't want.  If I reorder the template definitions then I get even more scary compiler warnings.  So where am I going wrong?  Is there a simpler way to do this?  Why is it picking the wrong template?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Any standard containers size will be represented a `size_t` which is a typedef for `unsigned long` usually. You should rethink your template parametrization.

Comment: *Please* present your code as a single complete piece we can directly compile and get the same error.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The question is simple, it doesn't generally require others to run my code.  I never asked anyone to run or debug my code.  If you're not a native speaker, let me help you, the way you worded that was extremely rude.  Let's try to make stackoverflow more welcoming.  All the best.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be rude, so apologies if it sounded that way. What I'm asking for isn't my whim, it's [one of the rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You're getting help from volunteers, and the minimal thing you can do to help them help you is to streamline their process, by providing a piece of code they can quickly run and debug. *"never asked anyone to run or debug"* Hm? You said "So where am I going wrong?", which, at least to me, is a request to debug the code. One of the answers below did exactly that.

Comment: *"doesn't generally require others to run my code"* I wasn't able to spot the error without running it.

Answer (score 3):

With C++17 you can use [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```cpp
template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
bool all_equal_in_size(Arg const& head, Args const&... tail){
    return  ( (tail.size() == head.size()) && ... );
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6MzjG35qh)

Comment: true :). I edited the answer accordingly

Comment: I'd use `std::size` to support plain arrays.

Answer (score 3):

With template and overload, you have to be careful with order (if you don't provide forward declaration).

```
template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
bool all_equal_in_size(Arg arg, Args... args) {
    auto size = arg.size();
    return (size == all_equal_in_size(size, args...)); // only see itself, and not other won't be found by ADL
}
```

in addition, you miss one case, in:

```
template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
bool all_equal_in_size(Arg arg, Args... args)
{
    auto size = arg.size();
    return (size == all_equal_in_size(size, args...));
}
```

With empty pack, you call `all_equal_in_size(size)` which can match only itself, adding

```
bool all_equal_in_size(std::size_t n) { return true; }
```

solves that.

So you have to order definition in right order (or providing forward declaration of the methods) and add missing overload:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WM9qKvKqK)

You can drop recursion with the unique function:

```
template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
bool all_equal_in_size(Arg arg, Args... args) {
    std::size_t sizes[] = {arg.size(), args.size()...};
    return std::all_of(sizes,
                       sizes + 1 + sizeof...(Args),
                       [&](std::size_t size){ return size == std::size(arg); });
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cc9b4TK7K)
or in C++17

```
template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
bool all_equal_in_size(Arg arg, Args... args) {
    return ((std::size(arg) == std::size(args)) && ... && true);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WGKhc8dr8)

Comment: @JeJo: [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) is C++17, OP tags C++11.

Comment: @JeJo: Indeed (I initially used `std::size`/`std::begin`/`std::end` with C++20, and when "migrating" to C++11 and fixing errors, I replace too many stuff it appears ;-) )